# Can't install Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Language Pack (english) as additional language

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, language-packs

I downloaded the "vs_langpack.exe" file from tools--->environment --->international settings--->get additional languagues button , but the installation stops due a condition:

> [284C:0F54][2018-02-09T12:48:56]i052: Condition 'NOT (IEsvcVersionExists) OR (IEsvcVersion < v10.0)' evaluates to false.
>
> [0CEC:1AD0][2018-02-09T15:08:40]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: CommunityBlock : Microsoft Visual Studio is required, but it is not installed on this computer. Please install it and retry.

This is not true, as you can see from the picture linked below.

[Info about Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZJB1.png)

System Info: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1

Can anyone help me fix the issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: The shell version is a distinct product with its own language pack.  That it sends you off to the wrong download location does not appear to entirely be a mystery.  The shell is discontinued in VS2017 and the previous download locations for the shell language pack are no longer available.  I suspect you'll have to call Microsoft Support to get ahead.

Comment: Thanx for the info @HansPassant